# Difficulties in extracting data from CSV and matching it with Product model

Tags: python, django

I have a Django Python project where I’m trying to build an application where you can upload a csv file to then extract its values to generate a sales report pdf. Products can be added via the admin console and if those items appear (at the right place for now, eg item 4 in each row gets checked on) in the csv file they get extracted and added to the report (calculating the sum, storing the date of each purchase).

The csv file is as follows:

```
POS,Transaction id,Product,Quantity,Customer,Date
1,E100,TV,1,Test Customer,2022-09-19
2,E100,Laptop,3,Test Customer,2022-09-20
3,E200,TV,1,Test Customer,2022-09-21
4,E300,Smartphone,2,Test Customer,2022-09-22
5,E300,Laptop,5,New Customer,2022-09-23
6,E300,TV,1,New Customer,2022-09-23
7,E400,TV,2,ABC,2022-09-24
8,E500,Smartwatch,4,ABC,2022-09-25
```

I’m having 2 main problems, the first is that following a tutorial with someone using a Mac (I’m on Windows but also saving the csv file in Macintosh format didn’t fix this) the code he uses just doesn’t work for me. It literally returns an empty string:

```py
with open(obj.csv_file.path, 'r') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                reader.__next__()
                for row in reader:
                    data = "".join(row)
                    data = data.split(';')
                    data.pop()
```

My workaround here is then to write the following code which generates a string separated by ‘;’:

```py
for row in reader:
                    print(row,type(row))
                    data = " ".join(row)
                    data = data.split(";")
```

As part of this first problem I’m currently unable to grab the elements. I’m thinking that I probably need to convert the values into a list, but there’s a problem to that which is my main problem.

Going further in the code:

```py
transaction_id = data[1]
                    product = data[2]
                    quantity = int(data[3])
                    customer = data[4]
                    date = parse_date(data[5])

                    print(transaction_id, product, quantity, customer, date)

                try:
                    product_obj = Product.objects.get(name__iexact=product)
                except Product.DoesNotExist:
                    product_obj = None
                
        return HttpResponse()
```

The terminal prints out:

```
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
file is being uploaded
['1', 'E100', 'TV', '1', 'Test Customer', '9/19/2022'] <class 'list'>
['1 E100 TV 1 Test Customer 9/19/2022'] <class 'list'>
(…)
transaction_id = data[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It turns out the product_obj always has the value **None** which it also had when I was playing around with the iteration where I occasionally could grad elements but never product_obj which is constantly set to None.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when split at semi-colon (`;`) (i.e. `data = data.split(";")`) when there are no present in your data? I don't see how you get to this output `1;E100;TV;1;Test;Customer;9/19/2022` with your current code. For this, you need `data = ";".join(row)` instead of `data = " ".join(row)`. I think this is not the code that produce the output

Comment: hi buran thanks for your reply. Yes you are right, I getting that earlier but currently getting  ```['1', 'E100', 'TV', '1', 'Test Customer', '9/19/2022'] <class 'list'>
['1 E100 TV 1 Test Customer 9/19/2022'] <class 'list'>```  and also that ```transaction_id = data[1]
IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: Please, edit your question to include the actual code you run alongside the relevant output and current error. Also, most certainly, the whole Django part is irrelevant and should  be removed (i.e. post [mre])

Comment: Also, given that csv file has headers, it may be much more convenient to use `csv.DictReader`. Even if you stick to `csv.reader`, it will yield list of fields in the row and there is no need to join the row, then split it back, etc.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I just updated the initial question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `csv.reader` - no need to join and then split back row, etc.

```
with open(obj.csv_file.path, 'r') as f:
    rdr = csv.reader(f)
    next(rdr) # skip the header row

    # alternative 1
    for row in rdr:
        pos, transaction_id, product, quantity, customer, transaction_date = row
        # here work with product to check if exists

    # alternative 2
    for pos, transaction_id, product, quantity, customer, transaction_date in rdr:
        # here work with product to check if exists
```

Using `csv.DictReader`:

```
with open(obj.csv_file.path, 'r') as f:
    rdr = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in rdr:
        product = row['Product'] # this will work even when column order/number has changed
        # here work with product to check if exists
```

Now I see this is your third question in a row on the same problem. You've got some good working code and some ill advise. Anyway, it doesn't look like you actually try to understand the code you are given.

Comment: oh ok! yes, I'm getting a dictionary as a result of this, very nice: ```file is being uploaded
{'POS': '1', 'Transaction id': 'E100', 'Product': 'TV', 'Quantity': '1', 'Customer': 'Test Customer', 'Date': '9/19/2022'} <class 'dict'>``` -- I get a key error at the end, but will need to check this a little later with more time ```transaction_id = row[1]
KeyError: 1```

Comment: well, the dict keys are the strings from header row, not indexes/int. See the dict and my example `product = row['Product']`. As I said in my answer - I seethis is your third question in a row on the same problem. You've got some good working code and some ill advise. Anyway, it doesn't look like you actually try to understand the code you are given.

Comment: fair enough, I'm currently at work and need to look into this more dedicated later this afternoon. I'm new to coding in general, your comments are indeed very helpful, I had no idea where to look before you posted the answers. I will need some time to do the understanding and implementing it properly. Appreciate your help, buran :)